# User Interface/ Front End with Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, frontend

I'm in the process of developing a website for travel planner. It is my first time to use a web framework which will be Django, I have no idea about it, but I'm in the learning process. I'm trying to figure out how I can integrate my front end or the HTML, CSS, And java script into dingo. I mean I'm going for Django as a back end and I don't know if Django has the ability to facilitate a front end design, I'm concerned a lot about design, so I want to feel free to play around with the front end. So, is there is any way that I can code my own pages in notpad++ and add them to Django as web pages or any platform I should use in order to integrate the front end with Django? Just because prior to my research about Django the front end templating that Django provides has other scripts than CSS and HTML and I honestly have no idea what does that mean! So a little feedback about this would really make a huge help!

Comment: https://jeffknupp.com/blog/2014/03/03/what-is-a-web-framework/

Answer (score 0):

Django can be integrated with frontend easily.

Use python to write backend, use django template language to integrate frontend. Just be free to write your own html, css.

This should **not** be a problem.

As for the platform, it is also **not** a problem, python is cross-platform, so django can be used to most platforms.

Comment: Thanks! But I know the basic Html, not the Django template language, so any alternatives?

Comment: Django template language is easy enough that you can learn it within short time. If you want to integrate front end in Django, then you have to learn a kind of template language in order to render your front end pages.

Comment: would Bootstrap help in this situation ?

Comment: To be frank, no. Bootstrap just works in front end pages. Moreover, Bootstrap is just a collection of css and js(of course there are related resources like fonts).

Comment: If you really do not want to learn a kind of template language, then use ajax to separate front end from back end. But this means you have to spend more time(just my opinion).

Answer (score 0):

First develop a backend api. In django you can have your views return json data.

In your front end you just call the django api and render the json data returned by the api.

If you are using Django for the first time, I suggest you first understand basics of django framework. [MDN Django tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django) is a good place to start.